# Safari mobile emulation for web app via Selenium

Tags: selenium, mobile, safari

Need to test responsive design for web app. I understand that browser didn't emulate like real device or even device emulator, but i don't need it.
Note: i'm looking for not to run Safari inside emulator, but to activate mobile emulation in Safari

**question 1**:
Is it possible to start Safari via selenium with predefined mobile emulation, like in Chrome [here](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/mobile-emulation)

```
Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Nexus 5");
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

if answer **no**(assume it will be no), **question 2**:
 is it enough to resize Safari window to required device viewport size?

Answer (score 2):

Setting the browser width isn't enough as many of today's web pages use the useragent as a means to determine the device that is viewing the page. Afaik, there is no way and I've been trying to find a solution to this for a while. Safari doesn't give automated control to set the user agent nor the mobile mode of its desktop browser.

There is a way to do what you want here though: https://webkit.org/blog/9395/webdriver-is-coming-to-safari-in-ios-13/

But the requirement is you need an iPhone connected to your laptop to run the test from and you need to add these capabilities to your configuration

```
safari:deviceType
safari:useSimulator
```

Read the man file for safaridriver for more info.

If you need to set the useragent, you can do it via the command line, but you need to reset it after https://tarunlalwani.com/post/selenium-change-user-agent-different-browsers/

Comment: yeah, already done with cmd solution, looks like that's the only way.

Comment: @user3535807, Can you please post your solution as an answer on this question. So it would be help others. Thanks